# Confusion with Visual Studio 2010 Directives

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have two Visual Studio 2010 projects named `OldProject` and `NewProject`, both full of `.cs` files.

I want to use `OldProject`'s `OldFile.cs` file in `NewProject`'s `NewFile.cs` file.

At the top of `NewFile.cs`, I wrote `using OldFileNamespace;` to no avail. I tried setting reference paths to no avail. I tried copying `OldFile.cs` into `NewProject` to no avail, since there are many `using` directives in `OldFile.cs` which `NewProject` does not recognize.

What else can I do?

Comment: Have you tried referencing `OldProject` in `NewProject`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **simply need to refer the project to your new project**.

If for some reason it doesn't work (**it should work**), create a new class library, add the .cs class in it and refer to it. It does not change anything. But if the classes are only used to be refered to another project, this is a good practice.

```
myClassLibrary.dll
```

Don't forget to include it with the `using` keyword once you added the reference.

### Create the class library

> [image]

### Once you build it, find where you `.dll` is.

> [image]

### Add the reference to your project

> [image]

### Don't forget the `using` statement

> [image]

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but how can I create a `.dll` file?

Comment: @JuniorProgrammer You simply create a ClassLibrary type of project and build it. Once it is done go into your project folder's bin and your `.dll` will be there. I'll add pictures.

Comment: It's worth noting that a dll is created by MSBUILD when a project is compiled.  A dll is simply the compiled output of a ClassLibrary

Comment: @DavidL It does not change anything indeed.That's why I said refering the project should work. But I think it is good practice in the case where the classes are only used to be refered. It's a waste of time but since OP didn't know how to make a reference to the old project I though it was a good idea to explain how to refer to a `.dll`.

Comment: A good point indeed :).  I just wanted to make sure the OP also understood WHAT a dll is, not just how to make one.

Comment: @JuniorProgrammer Look at my updated answer to see how to create it. Also read David's answer because it's the way it should be done if you don't *need* a class library.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to include the reference to `OldProject` as a PROJECT level reference.

Right click your project and click "Add Reference".

Use browse and browse to the file location of OldProject.dll.  Add it.

You should now be able to include and access the namespace for OldProject.